# get the name of Model class from which the page is inherited in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

public static class WebViewPageExtensions
    {
        public static string RenderMenu(this WebViewPage wp,string CategoryType)
        {        }         }

Above is a static class , whose function RenderMenu is calling on layout page in MVC3 , In my application all Viewpages are inherited from same layout page and different model classes, So whenever the page refresh or new viewPage is load above method RenderMenu is called. I want know the Name of Model class from which the page is inherited

I have tried   wp.Model

but as the Model names are dynamic , I am not able to get return of wp.model

Answer (score 2):

The Model property is of type object. You could inspect its type:

```
public static class WebViewPageExtensions
{
    public static string RenderMenu(this WebViewPage wp, string CategoryType)
    {        
        string modelTypeName = wp.Model.GetType().Name;
        ...
    }
}
```